# Appending "id=" parameter in Html.ActionLink in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 @Html.ActionLink("View Details", "Index", "PatientVisitDetail", new {id=item.Id}, null)|
```

produces some link like, **`http://localhost:19456/PatientVisitDetail/Index/1`**

But, I want a link that says something like,

**`http://localhost:19456/PatientVisitDetail/Index/?id=1`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is likely due to how your routing is setup. Not sure if there is a better way, but this should work:

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Index", "PatientVisitDetail") + "?id=" + item.Id)">View Details</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the work around. It did help. But, can you guide me whats the problem in my code so I could improve

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.: There isn't really anything wrong with your code, your first URL is perfectly valid and will work with your application. But check out your `Global.asax` file, specifically the `RegisterRoutes` function - that is where you define how parameters like Id are used within the URL

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Will do. BTW, your solution works great.